# Trying to find parent selectors outside of ajax returned data

Tags: jquery

I have a list, like this:

```
<ul>
  <li class="service-well">
    <div class="service-header"><h1>Service Name</h1></div>
    ... lost of children, and children of children in here.
    <ul class="comments">
      <li class="comment-holder">
          ....This is a comment
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
```

Basically, it's a service, and people can post comments on it. When someone posts a comment, the comment is sent to the database, and then retrieved after insertion via ajax, and appended to:

```
<ul class="comments">
```

In my ajax success, I want to climb up the parents of that comment to grab the name of the service that it's related to:

```
success: function(data) {
  var serviceTitle = $(data).closest('.service-well').find('.service-header').find('h1').text();
  console.log(serviceTitle);
}
```

Now this works if I use the console in Chrome after the data is returned, but for some reason I'm getting nothing at all when watching the console for the logged service title. The data that's being returned is:

```
<li class="comment-holder">stuff here</li>
```

I am however easily able to filter and find selectors from WITHIN the li data being returned, but can't seem to get to parents outside of it.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you so much!

Comment: I've had a problem with using Data stricyly to find something.  Try instead saying `$(.comments li').last().closest('.service-well')...`

Comment: I don't see where you append comment to `ul` comments

Comment: Is the hole Html in data var?

Comment: @AdrianoGalessoAlves the entire <li class="comment-holder">stuff</li> is what's returned if I console.log(data);

Answer (score 1):

```
success: function(data) {
    var serviceTitle = $(data)..
```

In this case, **$(data)** is not referencing the list item that is currently in the DOM. You are instead creating a new jQuery object from the HTML received from your AJAX request. At this point, the element does not exist in the DOM, and therefore can not be used as a reference point for traversal. **.closest(..)** would not be appropriate here.

Instead, you may want to try something like this:

```
var serviceClass = $(data).attr('class');
var serviceTitle = $('.comments').find('.' + serviceClass).closest('.service-well').find('.service-header').find('h1').text();
```

After this, the **serviceTitle** variable contains the correct "service header."

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working, although still investigating.

Comment: I appreciate your help. Please see my answer posted.

Answer (score 1):

After appending to `comments` try this:

```
var serviceTitle = $('.comments .service-well:last .service-header h1').text();
```

Updated:

```
var serviceTitle = $(data).find('.service-well:first .service-header h1').text();
```

Comment: The problem with this is there are multiple services on the page, each with their own comment block.

Comment: $(data) just contains the <li class="comment-holder">comment</li>. I'm needing to get outside of that several parents up. If I could figure out a way to create/attach a selector to the li element within data then I should be good.

Comment: I appreciate your help. Please see my answer posted.

Answer (score 0):

I feel rather silly for not attempting this to begin with. I solved my problem by capturing the service title BEFORE the ajax function.